# Attempting to setup Exchange account in System Preferences causes crash

Tags: crash, system-settings, accounts, exchange, console

I have two computers both installed with OSX 10.9.2 and on one computer I did this with no problem what so ever but on the other computer, when I attempt to setup my Exchange account in the System Preferences>Internet Accounts menu, it throws this error:

There was an error in Internet Accounts preference pane.

Having looked for a solution on Apple Discussion Forums, I have attempted to delete these files:

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.system preferences .plist

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.<12digitHexNumber>.plist

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist

/Library/Preferences/By Host/com.apple.systempreferences.xxx.plist of them)

/Library/Caches/com.apple.systempreferences

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist

followed by emptying my recycle-bin and restart the computer, but the problem persists.

### Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

---

### Console Excerpt ([Link to view complete Console report](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/9d85d7231ea4c8d6790e))

```
Process:         com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice [970]
Path:            /System/Library/PreferencePanes/InternetAccounts.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice
Identifier:      com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice
Version:         1.0 (1)
Build Info:      InternetAccounts-225004000000000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [1]
Responsible:     System Preferences [232]
User ID:         501
Date/Time:       2014-05-10 18:12:32.176 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C1021)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  F82228C3-4125-D958-C4C9-1F3EF208729F

Crashed Thread:  11

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: serverName)' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException abort() called
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.. After looking more closely at the log and mulling over it for a moment I noticed in the log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: serverName)'
```

So I attempted to setup the account in Preferences>Internet Accounts again but this time, I started the process with all of my internet connections disabled.  So I disabled the wifi and ethernet adapters beforehand.  Now, when after entering my info, and selecting continue instead of crashing it displayed a new window requesting that I manually enter the server address.  I manually entered the server, reactivated my network connection, and selected continue, at which point it completed successfully.

The problem must be that when the system attempts to find the server automatically it fails to find it, and rather than request it manually, it crashes.  But if there is no internet connection its forced to request the information since it is unable to search for it.

[image]